# Align legends to each heatmap in a ComplexHeatmap with 2 heatmaps

Tags: r, rna-seq, heatmap

I have created a ComplexHeatmap containing 2 `Heatmap`s, each with their own legend. The legend on the first Heatmap is continuous, whereas that of the second is discrete.

When I concatenate these `Heatmap`s vertically, and `draw` the `HeatmapList`, their legends are auto-aligned to the center of the plot. Is there any way I can have these legends positioned centered to the respective heatmaps and not to the center of the plot?

This is what I have:

[image: Current_Image]

Here's what I'd like to have:

[image: Desired_Image]

How can I go about solving this problem? I'd really like to avoid creating customized `Legend`s if I can, but if that's what it takes, that works too.

Thank you in advance for any help/pointers!

Note: I tried adding the `ComplexHeatmap` tag, but it doesn't exist yet and I don't have the reputation to create new tags yet.

Edit: Since this is a Bioconductor package, I also created an identical post on the [Bioconductor support forum](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/120958/)

Dummy data and code:

```
devtools::install_github('jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap');
library(ComplexHeatmap);
library(viridis);

dummy_top_mat <- structure(c(0.4563, 0.2211, 1.2235, 0.067, 1.6859, 1.0936, 0.4533, 
1.6844, 1.0039, 0.5402, 0.6841, 1.498, 1.042, 0.1711, 0.3565, 
2.2814, 3.0516, 1.5012, 0.5367, 3.0846, 1.1909, 0.235, 1.4266, 
0.4858, 2.9054, 0.3733, 0.6902, 0.8555, 0.4234, 2.6778, 0.1568, 
0.5556, 2.0172, 0.8034, 2.2897, 0.1166, 3.8033, 0.1431, 2.0606, 
1.2725, 1.5365, 0.4123, 1.2087, 1.1264, 0.8334, 1.1943, 1.58, 
1.5849, 0.3004, 0.3722, 0.0362, 0.0532, 1.4867, 0.4053, 0.3615, 
0.0897, 1.3217, 1.1447, 1.3058, 0.1903, 0.1067, 0.9482, 1.3382, 
3.2955, 0.391, 1.0418, 0.2041, 1.208, 1.5857, 3.5313, 0.472, 
1.389, 0.2143, 0.0226, 0.029, 0.444, 2.0521, 0.3955, 0.3495, 
0.5062, 1.3236, 1.3234, 0.7111, 0.1176, 2.2223, 1.2073, 0.3964, 
2.1175, 0.3382, 0.2816, 0.71, 3.1417, 0.2402, 0.5793, 0.7662, 
1.6782, 0.0986, 0.087, 0.5447, 2.6672, 1.2498, 1.0676, 1.8608, 
1.8146, 0.1422, 0.4221, 0.0303, 0.9541, 0.7358, 1.7664, 1.5144, 
0.2034, 0.9366, 0.7837, 0.3284, 0.1477, 1.8306, 1.3564, 0.1126, 
0.0171, 2.9858, 0.0233, 0.2796, 0.6995, 1.6081, 0.215, 1.7093, 
0.5178, 1.7061, 2.473, 1.8912, 0.7661, 4.4102, 1.2963, 0.6542, 
0.4281, 0.4491, 0.6, 0.4076, 1.6869, 0.4747, 3.9823, 1.1226, 
2.7355, 2.7036, 0.2241, 0.983, 1.0992, 1.4736, 0.1584, 0.2995, 
0.2272, 0.5744, 0.9314, 0.6924, 0.0812, 1.361, 0.727, 0.1525, 
1.3367, 0.566, 2.7801, 0.2349, 3.2655, 1.0675, 0.449, 0.5411, 
0.8291, 0.52, 0.0507, 0.6538, 0.4636, 1.2063, 0.9784, 0.1925, 
0.0756, 0.136, 1.2529, 0.317, 0.0281, 0.8668, 3.4138, 5.3898, 
0.521, 0.087, 3.4819, 0.1114, 0.0061, 0.9804, 1.139, 1.4159, 
1.0297, 0.6503, 1.0828, 2.3527, 0.057, 0.5602, 0.4017, 0.9985, 
0.8673), .Dim = c(10L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(c("gene01", "gene02", 
"gene03", "gene04", "gene05", "gene06", "gene07", "gene08", "gene09", 
"gene10"), c("sample01", "sample02", "sample03", "sample04", 
"sample05", "sample06", "sample07", "sample08", "sample09", "sample10", 
"sample11", "sample12", "sample13", "sample14", "sample15", "sample16", 
"sample17", "sample18", "sample19", "sample20")));

dummy_bottom_mat <- structure(c("Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive"), .Dim = c(6L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(c("marker1", 
"marker2", "marker3", "marker4", "marker5", "marker6"), c("sample01", 
"sample02", "sample03", "sample04", "sample05", "sample06", "sample07", 
"sample08", "sample09", "sample10", "sample11", "sample12", "sample13", 
"sample14", "sample15", "sample16", "sample17", "sample18", "sample19", 
"sample20")));

hmap1 <- Heatmap(dummy_top_mat, col = colorRampPalette(viridis(15))(100), name = 'log2 (TPM)', na_col = 'grey60', cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_columns = FALSE, row_names_side = 'left', column_title_side = 'top', rect_gp = gpar(col='white', lwd=0.5), height=unit(10*0.75,'cm'), width = unit(20*0.75, 'cm'), column_title = 'Gene Expression');

hmap2 <- Heatmap(dummy_bottom_mat, col = c('Negative'='red', 'Positive'='blue'), na_col = 'grey60', row_split = factor( c('gp1','gp1','gp1','gp1','gp2','gp2'), c('gp1','gp2'), ordered = TRUE), name = 'Marker\nStatus', rect_gp = gpar(col='white',lwd=1), row_title = NULL, height = unit(6*0.75,'cm'), width = unit(20*0.75, 'cm'), row_names_side = 'left', column_title = 'Biomarkers');

draw(hmap1 %v% hmap2, ht_gap = unit(1, 'cm'), auto_adjust = FALSE);

sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Users/ram/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] viridis_0.5.1        viridisLite_0.3.0    ComplexHeatmap_2.1.0 forcats_0.4.0       
 [5] stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.0.1        purrr_0.2.5          readr_1.3.1         
 [9] tidyr_0.8.3          tibble_2.1.1         ggplot2_3.1.1        tidyverse_1.2.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0          lubridate_1.7.4     lattice_0.20-38     circlize_0.4.6      prettyunits_1.0.2  
 [6] png_0.1-7           ps_1.3.0            rprojroot_1.3-2     assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.18      
[11] R6_2.3.0            cellranger_1.1.0    plyr_1.8.4          backports_1.1.4     reprex_0.2.1       
[16] httr_1.4.0          pillar_1.3.1        GlobalOptions_0.1.0 rlang_0.3.1         lazyeval_0.2.2     
[21] readxl_1.3.1        rstudioapi_0.10     callr_3.2.0         GetoptLong_0.1.7    desc_1.2.0         
[26] devtools_2.0.2      munsell_0.5.0       broom_0.5.2         compiler_3.5.1      modelr_0.1.4       
[31] pkgconfig_2.0.2     pkgbuild_1.0.3      shape_1.4.4         tidyselect_0.2.5    gridExtra_2.3      
[36] crayon_1.3.4        withr_2.1.2         nlme_3.1-137        jsonlite_1.6        gtable_0.3.0       
[41] magrittr_1.5        scales_1.0.0        cli_1.1.0           stringi_1.4.3       remotes_2.0.4      
[46] fs_1.3.1            xml2_1.2.0          generics_0.0.2      rjson_0.2.20        RColorBrewer_1.1-2 
[51] tools_3.5.1         glue_1.3.0          hms_0.4.2           processx_3.3.1      pkgload_1.0.2      
[56] parallel_3.5.1      clue_0.3-57         colorspace_1.4-1    cluster_2.0.7-1     sessioninfo_1.1.1  
[61] rvest_0.3.3         memoise_1.1.0       haven_2.1.0         usethis_1.5.0
```

Comment: I think this is more suitable for GitHub issues "feature request". Currently if we add legends manually using `draw(..., Legend(), ...)` then we can use **"just"** argument within `draw()` to define position. But if we want to adjust existing legend within `Heatmap` function using `Heatmap(..., heatmap_legend_param = list(` it doesn't have **"just"** argument. (See 5.4 Section of the manual).

Comment: Even with `just`, it seems to be more along the lines of "where in the image" than "where with respect to the heatmap this legend belongs to". I will open a GitHub issue though, maybe the dev has a line of thought for this.

Comment: Here's the issue I opened on GitHub: https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is not possible. Concatenating two heatmaps causes their legends to be grouped, and while they can be positioned together at the top, bottom, at the left or the right sides, they cannot be separated spatially.

The discussion can be viewed at the bioconductor support link from the question. Relevant snippets:

> No, since you put the two heatmaps as one plot, the legends are grouped. You can either edit in Inkscape or make two heatmaps in two plots. You can get the column (order) of the first heatmap ... and assign to the second heatmap

> The thing is if you add two heatmaps, the legends are always plotted together. One way I can think to improve this is to move the legends to the bottom of the heatmap.

Comment: Thanks for replying